# Synchronization for nested collections

Tags: backbone.js, synchronization

Suppose I have models:

```
var Book = Backbone.Model.extend({
  // ... 
});

var Store = Backbone.Model.extend({
  getBooks: function(){
    this.books = new Books(App.Singletons.AllBooks.where({storeId: this.id}));
    return this.books;
  }
});
```

Store `has many` books.

Also suppose I have a collection:

```
var Books = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Book
});
```

In a complex business logic I need a base store object for the Books:

```
var App = App || {};
App.Singletons = App.Singletons || {};
var books = new Books();
books.fetch();
App.Singletons.AllBooks = books;
// ...
```

What the best way for syncing a singleton model for operations like this:

```
var store = new Store({id: 1});
store.fetch();
store.getBooks();

store.books.add(...);
store.books.remove(...);
// etc
// There I need to sync with App.Singletons.AllBooks
```

Now I'm overriding these methods in the `Books` collections. And there the `App.Singletons.AllBooks` is being synced.
I think there should be another better solution for this task. 
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep something in "sync", override the sync method.

In the case of store:

```js
var Store = Backbone.Model.extend({
  getBooks: function() {
    this.books = new Books(App.Singletons.AllBooks.where({
      storeId: this.id
    }));
    return this.books;
  },
  sync: function(method, model, options) {
    switch (method) {
      case 'create':
        //your logic to sync with App.Singletons.AllBooks
        break;
      case 'read':
        //your logic to sync with App.Singletons.AllBooks
        break;
      case 'update':
        //your logic to sync with App.Singletons.AllBooks
        break;
      case 'delete':
        //your logic to sync with App.Singletons.AllBooks
        break;
    }
  }
  Backbone.prototype.sync.call(this, method, method, options);
});
```